# text gradient by using image

Tags: text, css

This is how to make gradient text only for WebKit , I found it from [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/) !

```
h1 {
     font-size: 72px;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   }
```

Is there any way to make text's color gradient by using x-repeated gradient image ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it using a gradient image, just overlay the image on the text

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXqH8/)

```
<div class="gradient1">
    <h1><span></span>CSS Gradient Text</h1>
</div>

.gradient1 h1 {
    font: bold 330%/100% "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0 50px;
    color: #464646;
}
.gradient1 h1 span {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrgB0.png) repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 31px;
}
```

[Credits](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-gradient-text/)

Edit: If you are interested in using only CSS solution, which I think will support most of the browsers

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXqH8/1/)

```
<span>Isn't this awesome?</span>

span {
    position:relative;
    font-size: 30px;    
}

span:after {
    content: "";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these two links:

The first is a tool to create CSS gradients online
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

The second is a MS tool, to create data urn svg gradients to use in IE9+
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

Combine the two (best with modernizr.com) and you might have what you wanted (depends on how complicated the gradient is)